# One-time event fire that is subscribed to another event

Tags: c#, events

```
public event EventHandler ConstructDesign;
public DataGridView dataGrid = new DataGridView();
public FooClass(Action action) {
    ConstructDesign+=action;
    dataGrid.DataBindingComplete+=ConstructDesign;
}

public void Launch() {
    ConstructDesign(null, new EventArgs());
}

//IN A COMPLETELY DIFFERENT CLASS:
public void Main(string[] args) {
    var launcher = new FooClass(Fire);
    launcher.Launch();
}

public void Fire(object sender, EventHandlerArgs args...) {
    Console.WriteLine("Fired");
    //and after the first fire, action will be removed from the `ConstructDesign`.
}
```

So basically what I'm trying to achieve here is how to do the following:
An `Action` that is added manually through code to `ConstructDesign` and upon firing, it will removes itself from the event handler, `ConstructDesign`. any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't found a nice way to unsubscribe from the event after the first use.  (You could certainly use a reflection-heavy approach, but I doubt the compiler would complain if a refactoring changed the name of an event).

Here is one that uses only delegates, so the compiler would still serve you well.  It may not be as light-weight as you need, but since I took up the challenge for my own edification, I thought I'd share it.

```
MyEvent += SingleUseEventHandler<AssemblyLoadEventArgs, AssemblyLoadEventHandler>
   .Create(This_MyEventOccurred);
```

Where the magic is defined here:

```
public class SingleUseEventHandler<TArgs,THandler>
  where TArgs : EventArgs
{
  public static THandler Create(EventHandler<TArgs> handler)
  {
     var helper = new SingleUseEventHandler<TArgs, THandler>(handler);
     EventHandler<TArgs> h = helper.InvokeIfFirstTime;
     return (THandler)(object)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(THandler), h.Target, h.Method);
  }

  public void InvokeIfFirstTime(object sender, TArgs args)
  {
     if (!raised)
     {
        raised = true;
        handler(sender, args);
     }
  }

  public SingleUseEventHandler(EventHandler<TArgs> handler)
  {
     this.handler = handler;
  }

  bool raised;
  readonly EventHandler<TArgs> handler;
}
```

Of course, C# won't infer the delegate type, so you have to specify it explicitly.

If the event's definition is EventHandler, you can use this instead:

```
MyEvent += SingleUseEventHandler<SomeEventArgs>.Create(SomeHandlerMethod);


public static class SingleUseEventHandler<TArgs>
  where TArgs : EventArgs
{
  public static EventHandler<TArgs> Create(EventHandler<TArgs> handler)
  {
     var helper = new SingleUseEventHandler<TArgs, EventHandler<TArgs>>(handler);
     return helper.InvokeIfFirstTime;
  }
}
```

Here's an example program:

```
class Program
{
  static event AssemblyLoadEventHandler MyEvent;
  static int callCount;
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
     MyEvent += SingleUseEventHandler<AssemblyLoadEventArgs, AssemblyLoadEventHandler>
        .Create(Load);

     foreach(var assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
     {
        Console.WriteLine("Raising event for " + assembly.GetName().Name);
        MyEvent(null, new AssemblyLoadEventArgs(assembly));
     }
  }

  static void Load(object sender, AssemblyLoadEventArgs eventArgs)
  {
     Console.WriteLine(++callCount);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can stop the event from firing but you can stop code inside the event from executing. It's really easy, add a `static bool` at the class level, initialize it to `true`, set it to `false` after the first execution. Wrap the code inside the event handler in `if (firstExecution) {//actions I only want executed the first time the event fires}`

Comment: I've considered this option, but I believe there can be a better solution. thanks.

Comment: Also this turns out to be more problematic when that specific method, `Fire` is being launched in other events, so I can't use your suggestion unless I'll check the sender object to determine from where it was launched.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you have events in your class, because you don't subscribe to them anywhere. Invoke passed action instead:

```
Action _action;

public FooClass(Action action) 
{
    _action = action;
}

public void Launch() 
{
    if (_action == null)
        return;

     _action();
     _action = null;        
}
```

Comment: The event 'ConstructDesign' can only appear on the left hand side of += or -= (except when used from within the class 'FooClass'.
I did not think it will make any difference, I edited the code on the first post.

Comment: @NucS Event appears only on the left hand side of `-=` operator. Whats the problem here?

Comment: `ConstructDesign` is the one that needs to be removed from `otherHandler`.
And it is located outside of `FooClass` and I may actually solved it, I'll post an answer if it will work.

Comment: I've solved the problem either way.
Thanks a lot for the effort.

Answer (score 0):

An event will only fire if it has subscribers, so couldn't you just remove the delegate via `-=`, or am I misunderstanding what you want to do?

Comment: I believe the OP wants a functional way of doing just that.  Some notation to add a single-use handler.

Answer (score 0):

```
        public class FooEvents {
            public event EventHandler ConstructDesign;
            public DataGridView dataGrid = new DataGridView();
            public FooEvents(Action action) {
                ConstructDesign+=action;
                dataGrid.DataBindingComplete+=ConstructDesign;
                dataGrid.DataBindingComplete+=RemoveSubscribtion;
            }

            public void Launch() {
                ConstructDesign(this, new EventArgs()); //passes FooEvent and fires.
            }

            private void RemoveSubscribtion(object sender, EventArgs args) {
                 dataGrid.DataBindingComplete-=ConstructDesign;
                 dataGrid.DataBindingComplete-=RemoveSubscribtion;
            }

       public Main {
            public void Main(string[] args) {
                var launcher = new FooClass(Fire);
                launcher.Launch();
            }

            public void Fire(object sender, EventHandlerArgs args) {
                Console.WriteLine("Fired");
            }
       }
```